# Shibboleth IE11 IDP error on first redirection to IDP

Tags: internet-explorer-11, shibboleth, opensaml

I'm encountering an error only in Internet Explorer (tested in 9 and 11). Everything works as expected in Chrome and Firefox. 
The first time you attempt to go to an SP protected page and are redirected to the IDP, the IDP will redirect you back to the SP and display the following error: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCAH9.png

This only happens on the first attempt to authenticate. The second attempt will correctly show the login screen. 
It seems like the IDP is encountering an error and immediately redirecting back to the SP without ever giving the user a chance to login. As I'm not able to post multiple links, in comments I'll attach log excerpts from the IDP and SP logs for a specific transaction (server names and IPs have been anonymized).

I'm not familiar with trobleshooting IDP errors, so I don't have a lot of context on what this error could mean.
Thanks

Comment: IDP log excerpt: https://pastebin.com/5wFcnHxi

Comment: SP log excerpt: https://pastebin.com/JLvrauHA

Answer (score 0):

The problem ended up being the number of redirects associated with logging in. For some reason IE completely fails when going past a certain number of redirects while Chrome does not.